# find item from item name lookup api

Tags: java, c++, mysql, windows, string

I'm currently working on a project, 
I need something that I can provide a name, then it can return what kind of item it is.

Say I have word starcraft, 
then the API or some database can return something like game

```
or nba -> sports
or nike -> sports/shoe
or sadkljasd -> unknown
```

I saw something did this like months ago, but I can not recall.
I need something that has this kind functionality and data, and it does not have to be accurate

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) provides the kind of API you are looking for..

You can have a mapping from your item to their type.. In a Map, you store your mapping in the form of `Key-Value` Pair... If all your items are unique, it will be the best bet for you..

Here I will give a brief example of how a Map works.. Rest you can get from the link I have given..

```
Map<String, String> mapping = new HashMap<String, String>();  
mapping.put("nba", "sports");

String type = mapping.get("nba");

System.out.println(type);   // Will give you `sports`
```

And if you have `multiple` types for some items, you can have a `Mapping` from `items` to the `list` of their types: -

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mapping = 
                             new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection`.....

**-** Using `Map` will be appropriate at this stage...

**Eg:**

`Map<String, ArrayList<String>>  map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();`

**Or**

`Map<String, String>  map = new HashMap<String,String>();`